# Transaction logs for a specific address, but reverse the chronology

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I was wondering if it is possible to get transaction logs for a specific address on solana but sorted from the oldest to the newest.

```
const solanaweb3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const searchAddress = "Whatever address";
const endpoint =
  "My quicknode endpoint";
const solanaConnection = new solanaweb3.Connection(endpoint);

const getTransactions = async (address, numTx) => {
  const pubKey = new solanaweb3.PublicKey(address);
  let transactionList = await solanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubKey, {
    limit: numTx,
  });
  transactionList.forEach((transaction, i) => {
    const date = new Date(transaction.blockTime * 1000);
    console.log(`Transaction No: ${i + 1}`);
    console.log(`Signature: ${transaction.signature}`);
    console.log(`Time: ${date}`);
    console.log(`Status: ${transaction.confirmationStatus}`);
    console.log("-".repeat(20));
  });
  let signatureList = transactionList.map(
    (transaction) => transaction.signature
  );
  let transactionDetails = await solanaConnection.getParsedTransactions(
    signatureList
  );

  transactionList.forEach((transaction, i) => {});
};

getTransactions(searchAddress, 3);
```

With this I get the last 3 transactions of a given address, but what would I need to do to get the X first ?

Thanks

Comment: To put it simply: this isn't possible with the normal Solana RPC. Other services may offer this functionality, but I can't guarantee that it exists